# Use variable inside this in angular 5

Tags: angular

I'd like to use a variable inside my `this.`. I already did this but it was some time ago and i can't remember how to do it. Searching via Google or here brought me no results that helped me.

This is my code:

```
fieldFocused: String; (gets filled by another function)

const helper = this.fieldFocused;

this.[helper]Model = this.[helper]Model + this.keyboardKeyPressed;
```

So i'd like to have that my `this.[helper]Model` is "converted" to `this.usernameModel` which than gets the value of 'john', how would i do this?

[tl;dr]

I'm actually working on a raspberry pi 3 with a flipped screen so that it is usable like a big smartphone. No onscreenkeyboard fits my needs so that i created one on my own. There are three inputs, like i said: `username`, `password` and `ipaddress`. When the user now clicks one of those buttons, i set the `this.fieldFocused` to the field the user clicked and than i'd like to edit the model based on the field that was focused lastly.

1. User clicks into the username input
2. `this.focusedInput` gets set to username
3. he presses key 'a' on the keyboard which calls a function
4. in dependency of the field focused i have to edit the model, this is why i need to use `this.focusedInput` inside another `this.` -> `this.[focusedInput]`

Comment: this["usernameModel"]

Comment: Sorry, i edited my question. `foo` is not always `username` that was just an example. `foo` gets filled by another function. It can be `username` `password` or `ipaddress`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is the bracket notation for property accessors: `this[helper + 'Model']`

**Updated code:**

```
fieldFocused: String; // (gets filled by another function)

const helper = this.fieldFocused;

this[helper + 'Model'] = this[helper + 'Model'] + this.keyboardKeyPressed;
```

[Further Reading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)

Comment: exactly what i was looking for! Thanks for also linking the docs